# Console Application with few tasks

Tags: c#

Basically, I need to write a C# console application that will take a 3-digit number and will do the following:
1. sum of all 3 digits (ex. if the number is 123 then it will be 6)
2. "refactor" his digits like that:
hundreds, tens, ones.
Example:
365
300+60+5=365
3. reverse the numbers

Much help appreciated.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: This looks very much like an homework assignment, so you should tag it as such, or explain why it isn't, so that we could give you the appropriate assistance for either case. Either way, you should include what you did try to solve this yourself.

Comment: I tried to calculate the sum of all three digits with the '%' (for example 256 % 100) and the output will be 2 but if I'd like to get the 5 and use 10 instead of 100 it won't work.

Comment: the % symbol means modulus in C#. This gives you the remainder after dividing the left side number with the right side one, e.g. 7%2 = 1 (7/2)=3 with remainder 1. 256%100 in C# should give you 56. Unless I'm reading your comment wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel taking risk to answer your question but what the hack..

> "refactor" his digits like that: hundreds, tens, ones.

```
int i = 123, reverse = 0;
while (i > 0)
{
    reverse = (reverse * 10) + (i % 10);
    i /= 10;
}
Console.WriteLine(reverse); //321
```

> sum of all 3 digits (ex. if the number is 123 then it will be 6)

```
int i = 123, total = 0;
while (i > 0)
{
    total += i % 10;
    i /= 10;
}
Console.WriteLine(total); //6
```

> Thanks but it's not what i meant by saying 'refactor'. For instance,
>   for the input 389 it'll print this: Hundreds: 3 Tens: 8 Ones: 9

```
int i = 389, houndreds = 0, tens = 0, ones = 0;

ones = i%10;
i /= 10;
tens = i%10;
i /= 10;
houndreds = i%10;

Console.WriteLine("Hundreds: {0} Tens: {1} Ones: {2}", houndreds, tens, ones); //Hundreds: 3 Tens: 8 Ones: 9
```

Comment: Thanks but it's not what i meant by saying 'refactor'.
For instance, for the input 389 it'll print this:
Hundreds: 3
Tens: 8
Ones: 9

Comment: @KyleButler Updated in my answer. Next time, make some effort for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is assuming that you have a 3 digit number for the refactor part:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int num = 365;
        char[] digits = num.ToString().ToCharArray();

        Console.WriteLine(digits.Sum(x=>char.GetNumericValue(x)));
        Console.WriteLine(new string(digits.Reverse().ToArray()));
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Hundreds: {0} Tens: {1} Ones: {2}", digits[0], digits[1], digits[2]));

        Console.Read();
    }
```